# Size of title - Product category / woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I would like to change the size of the title that is showing on product category page (woocommerce)

https://innovatefa.co.uk/product-category/all-sessions

I want to reduce the size as currently is being displayed as 75.768px

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually, by going to inspect element: left click on the heading and copy the name of class of heading. Then go to customize on upper black bar --> additional CSS and paste the name of the class that you copied with a dot(.) and then add curly brackets and inside brackets, add font-size that you want.

Like if class name is "heading1" and you want its size to be 20px, then do it like

.heading{

font-size : 20px;

}

Save this and check the results. Hope this will reduce the size of product heading.

Comment: you can use that code block to indent the code properly.